# Supressing the original output

Tags: shell

What or how does shell supress the output while using pipes in a script? Lets say we have code

```
cat file | wc -l
```

only the number of lines gets printed. Where does shell store the content of the file ? Same with for example find

```
find . -type f -exec grep -o 'hello' {} \; | wc -l
```

How does shell do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite nicely described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)).

So in your example:

```
cat file | wc -l
```

The output produced by `cat` is directed to the `stdout` stream which is connected via pipe to the `stdin` stream of `wc`.

As for actual implementation, each pipe is associated with a buffer of a certain size. This buffer is filled with data from `stdout` of the process on the left and consumed by `stdin` of the process on the right. Both processes are running in parallel and there is a mechanism to block the left process in case the right process isn't managing to consume all the data fast enough and the buffer is getting filled.

For more details go [here](https://brandonwamboldt.ca/how-linux-pipes-work-under-the-hood-1518/).

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the full technical answer, but in the examples you gave, the shell is simply connecting the stdout file descriptor to the stdin file descriptor of the second command.  The data isn't stored anywhere except for whatever memory is required to buffer the data as it passes from one process to another.